# XSLTListViewWebPart is not working in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have migrated my site from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 and changed the layout as well. Then I figured out that the pages which contains `XSLTListVeiwWebpart` stopped working as expected. Sorting, filtering, some of the context menu items are not working.

I read that it's been discontinued from SharePoint 2013 and it may not work as expected but could not figure out any workaround for the same.

Can anyone suggest me any workaround or a solution for this.

Comment: No where in that link I find information regarding this webpart being discontinued, also MS uses this webpart on all ther list pages. This webpart also works well in my 2013 projects. What exactly is the issue? Anything in the browser logs or ULS logs?

Comment: Sorry, I placed a wrong link. I could not find anything in logs or ULS logs. It's just the filtering, sorting and some items in context menu of any item are not working. When I try to sort the webpart on any column it doesn't sort it properly.